# asp:menu selected menu item highlight

Tags: asp.net

I'm using `asp:menu` for showing the menus in masterpage. If I click the menu item 1, the corresponding page is loading in the content page. I need that the selected menu item should be highlighted with some color. Please help me out.

Menu code is as follows:

```
<asp:menu id="NavigationMenu"
    staticsubmenuindent="10px" 
    orientation="Horizontal"
    runat="server" BackColor="#E3EAEB" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#666666">

    <items>
      <asp:menuitem text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx"></asp:menuitem>
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/page2.aspx" Text="About" value="About"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx" Text="Contact" Value="Contact"></asp:MenuItem>
    </items>
   <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
   <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
   <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" />
   <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
   <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
   <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" />
   <StaticItemTemplate>
       <%# Eval("Text") %>
   </StaticItemTemplate>
</asp:menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like the to select (and ultimately highlight) the active menu item.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MenuItem item in Menu1.Items)
        {
            if (Path.GetFileName(item.NavigateUrl).Equals(
                Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath), 
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: its showing like, Path does not exists in the correct context... can u pls tell me with respect to the above coding variables and ID used...

Comment: Path is in the System.IO namspace. Have you included that? 

You didn't include the first line of the <asp:menu /> declaration, so I assumed it was called Menu1.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a .sitemap and bind your menu to the sitemap.  The following link has a decent overview of using sitemaps with menus as well as how to enable security trimming for your menu.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

Comment: Was almost bashing my head against the wall in frustration and then I found this. Problem solved. Thanks!